# Spring rest: Consuming x-www-form-urlencoded associative array

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to PUT an associative array:

```
name[en_US]:Administrator
name[es_ES]:Administrador
name[no_NO]:Administrator
```

How do I configure the rest controller method to consume this data?
I have tried the following without any luck:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userGroupId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void updateUserGroup(    @PathVariable Long userGroupId,
                                @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) Map<String, String> name)
```

The data not passed as JSON, but as x-www-form-urlencoded.

EDIT 1:
If I leave out "(value = "name", required = false) from the @RequestParam I can get all request parameters as key value pairs, but isn't there a way to bind it to a Map? If not I would have to do some string manipulation to create that map manually.